# Read Office365 email on iPhone

Tags: email, office-365

I have an iPhone with iOS 16.7 installed.

I have Microsoft Outlook 4.2339.0 installed.

Here are the steps:

1. Open the Microsoft Outlook app.
2. Choose **Add account**.
3. Enter my Office365 email address
4. Click **Add account**
5. Choose **Outlook.com**
6. Observe I get "We couldn't find an account with that email address or phone number." error.

What can I do to be able to read my Office365 email on my iPhone?

Comment: Office365 and Outlook.com are two different things.  What is the account you use to signin to O365?

Comment: @Allan Yes.  the account I am trying to log into is a O365 paid account.

Comment: You should use “Exchange” and not O365.  Also remember that O365 has been retired , and is now called MS365. You may be experiencing any of the various  version compatible issues for this

Comment: "You should use “Exchange” and not O365".  I don't know what that means.  Do you mean I should install an app called exchange that use that?   Do you mean I should click on a button labeled exchange?  If so, where is that button?

Comment: I haven’t used O365 in a long time.  Don’t seek out that option; just look for Exchange. Are You trying to configure your mail settings manually?